# When calling the EventBusses in vueJS, one of them is not working at all

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, event-bus

So I have added a second bus to my code that runs on create, but no matter in which order I call the Busses the second bus (eventBus2) is never called and then returns no data. By printing some console logs I get the feeling that that eventBus2.$on is never executed. Is there some Vue rule that I'm not aware of, any suggestions?

> Item.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr
        v-for="item in info"
        :key="item.id"
        @click="editThisItem(item.id)"
      >
        <td>{{ item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{ item.number}}</td>
        <td>{{ item.size}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Something from "./Something.vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { eventBus } from "../main";
import { eventBus2 } from "../main";
export default {
  components: { Something },
  name: "Item",
  data() {
    return {
      selected_item_id: 0,
      info: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    editThisItem(bolt) {
      this.selected_item_id = bolt;
      eventBus2.$emit("itemWasSelected", this.selected_item_id);
      eventBus.$emit("newTabWasAdded", "edit-item");
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/items")
      .then((response) => (this.info = response.data._embedded.artikli));
  },
};
</script>
```

> EditItem.vue

```
<script>
import Something from "./Something.vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { eventBus2 } from "../main";
export default {
  components: { Something},
  name: "Edit-item",
  data() {
    return {
      info: null,
      select_number: 0,
      select_name: "",
      selected_item_id: -1,
      priv_item: {
      id: 0,
      size: "big"
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.selected_item_id != -1) {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:8080/items/" + this.selected_item_id)
        .then((response) => (this.priv_item = response.data));
    }
  },
  created() {
    eventBus2.$on("itemWasSelected", (data) => {
      this.selected_item_id = data;
      console.log(" + " + data);
      //this  console log does not even print the "+", the data is empty
    });
    console.log(this.selected_item_id);
  },
};
</script>
```

> main.js

```
export const eventBus = new Vue();
export const eventBus2 = new Vue();
```

Comment: You don't need multiple global event busses 1 is bad enough, should instead use a `something` vuex store and watch for the change on the model, which would change when you commit

Answer (score 0):

you're expecting `itemWasSelected` and emitting `WasSelected` they should be the same.

PD: that can be done in one line.

```
import { eventBus } from "../main";
import { eventBus2 } from "../main";
import { eventBus, eventBus2 } from "../main";
```

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a typo, when I correct that, still the result is the same.

Comment: the `console.log(this.selected_item_id);` log in the same created method print the value?

Comment: I added that console log to see if the value changed but it did not.

Comment: well if it's show the component it loaded before the emit, so I don't know what can be then, out of curiosity why do you need 2 buses?

Comment: One bus is for adding some new features and other one is for passing the data between 2   different child elements

Comment: you can use only one, there is no limit in events, check out [this](https://benbrougher.tech/vue-event-bus-tutorial/) how it uses an enum to keep event names formalized.